# SQL Server : join tables causes the data to duplicate on every row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query which is returning some redundant data. Can somebody please help me to correct this query. I have also attached the table relationship.

```
SELECT
   dbo.supplierOrder.sectionID,
   dbo.supplierOrder.supplierID,
   dbo.supplierOrder.supplierOrderNo,
   dbo.supplierOrder.supplierOrderCreated,
   dbo.supplierOrder.supplierOrderConfirmStatus,
   dbo.supplierOrderDetails.productID,
   dbo.supplierOrderDetails.orderQty,
   dbo.supplierOrderReceive.invoiceno,
   dbo.supplierOrderReceive.supplierInvoiceno,
   dbo.supplierOrderReceive.ID,
   dbo.supplierOrderReceiveDetail.qtyArrived
FROM
   dbo.supplierOrder
INNER JOIN
   dbo.supplierOrderDetails ON (dbo.supplierOrderDetails.supplierOrderID = dbo.supplierOrder.ID)
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.supplierOrderReceive ON (dbo.supplierOrderReceive.supplierOrderID = dbo.supplierOrder.ID)
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.supplierOrderReceiveDetail ON (dbo.supplierOrderReceiveDetail.supplierOrderReceiveID = dbo.supplierOrderReceive.ID)       
WHERE
   dbo.supplierOrder.ID = 1 ;
```

here is the output that I get

which is not exactly what I was want. the last column qtyArrived should show only its related qty but here as you can see it is repeating for each of the productID

[image]

and here is the db tables and relationship [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the last table should be join using also `ProductId` not only `OrderID` :

```
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.supplierOrderReceiveDetail
ON  
(dbo.supplierOrderReceiveDetail.supplierOrderReceiveID=dbo.supplierOrderReceive.ID)
AND 
(dbo.supplierOrderReceiveDetail.ProductID =dbo.sdbo.supplierOrderDetails.ProductID)
```

Comment: I was about to answer the same.! :)

Comment: Appreciate your help!!